# Infinite Scroll Only On Wordpress Mobile

Tags: infinite-scroll

I was wondering if it's possible to make only the Wordpress homepage (with the latest posts) have infinite scroll and keep the pagination on desktop view. I have viewed some other questions regarding this here but some of them are using plugins and some just want infinite loop on both desktop and mobile.

Comment: Can you post the code for your infinite scroll functionality or the code you plan to use.  If you're executing via javascript/jQuery then you can simply set whether or not the script executes based on window/screen width.  I've done this but the actual infinite scroll scripting is very specific to the site I was working on and would just include a lot of needless info.

Comment: I'm just running a simple loop, for now, I had no idea in which direction to even start with the code for the infinite loop so I have not made any and just moved on